# Calculating $\binom{n}{r} \bmod\; p$ where $p$ is prime and as large as $1000000007$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to calculate $\binom{n}{r}$ modulo $1000000007$. I have read [here](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/3869/best-known-algos-for-calculating-ncr-m)
about Lucas' Theorem but it seems to work for small values of $p$. Here $p = 1000000007$. Is there a way this can be solved? Thank you.

Comment: I take it by the use of "%" that you mean $\bmod \;p$?

Comment: Yes, I mean modulo p.

Comment: Since I see 1000000007 here I think this is programming contest problem. You'd better look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118137/fast-n-choose-k-mod-p-for-large-n

Comment: Yes, this is from a contest. I have the idea how to solve the problem, but this comes in the way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

By Legendre formula
$$
\Large
n!=\prod\limits_{p\in P,p\leq n} p^{\left(\sum\limits_{1\leq k\leq \log_p n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor\right)}
$$
where $P$ is the set of prime numbers. So to solve the problem you need to precompute primes less than $n$, and then optimize computation of formula given above.