# ($\binom{n+m}{n} \% p$). Where, $p$ is prime and $n, m, p$ are very large?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

$1 \le n,m \le 10^9$ and $p = 10^9 + 7$. This can be simply solved using factorials but it will take a lot of time. Lucas theorem is also inappropriate as $p$ is very large. Can this be approached in a more efficient way ?

Comment: Lucas' theorem tells you that you can replace $n + m$ with $n + m - p$, which should help. You can also try computing the relevant parts of Pascal's triangle recursively $\bmod p$.

Comment: A possible [useful link](http://fishi.devtail.io/weblog/2015/06/25/computing-large-binomial-coefficients-modulo-prime-non-prime/)

Comment: A similar [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249981/calculating-binomnr-bmod-p-where-p-is-prime-and-as-large-as-1000000?rq=1) and [a SO question for code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118137/fast-n-choose-k-mod-p-for-large-n)

Comment: And a sample random $n=156145098$ and $m=479622913$ if anyone ever feels like working an example.

Comment: @Joffan The answer to the question in the first link that you provided devises calculating primes which are less than n, but n is very large.

Comment: It covers a few different cases. There has certainly been more exploration of the smaller-$p$ cases.